# Why won't my AWS CodeDeploy run my script after deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am using CodeDeploy to deploy my applications to EC2 instances created by an Auto Scaling Group.

The applications deploy fine and are moved to their correct file mapped locations, however my `AfterInstallation` script is never executed. I can see in the logs that it tries to make the script executable and passes that stage, but it never gets executed.

Here is my appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /opt/lobby
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: bootstrap.sh
      timeout: 30
      runas: root
```

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup nodejs lobby.js &
echo "finished"
```

I do not see the echo printed nor do I see any processes running related to lobby.js. I can verify that this script works by typing ./bootstrap.sh after the deployment and this works fine. This hook should do this for me though.

This needs to be a background task as I will be running multiple applications in this script but only one is displayed now just to get it working.

---

Edit:

I have referred to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html#appspec-hooks-server and tried replacing AfterInstall with ValidateService and AfterAllowTraffic (but I'm not using a LoadBalancer)

**Question**

Why is my AfterInstallation script not getting called, or so it seems?

Comment: Are you certain that the file is in the same folder as appspec.yml? If so, try Location: ./bootstrap.sh

Comment: Yeah, I found the issue after a bit of digging. There were some errors being thrown in the execution log, and then I had to redirect the output of the background process to /dev/null or the deployment fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AfterInstall: AfterInstall script contains the tasks need to be executed after installing the Application.

Example of BeforeInstall script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu/production/weone-backend
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu/production
sudo NODE_ENV=production nohup nodejs app.js > /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null &
```

In the above script, we are changing the ownership of our application folder
& starting application process.

Note: Use “`/dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null &`” to get out of nohup shell automatically, else your CodeDeploy would get stuck at AfterInstall event.

https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/AWS-CodeDeploy